# Handling button clicks in recyclerview adapter (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter in which the items each have 3 buttons, that generate a dialog that then performs an action.  I have a sense that this should be removed from the adapter (I have view models available), but it works and I am wondering: Should I move logic to the fragment, to the view model, do I need to move it at all (is the code below bad practice and if so why)?  Any help/input would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the adapter code:

```
class ViewRecipesAdapter(val context: Context, private val recipes: List<Recipe>, private val parentFragment: Fragment) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewRecipesAdapter.RecipeViewHolder>()
{

    private var listToUse: List<Recipe> = recipes
    private lateinit var recipesViewModel: RecipesViewModel
    private var isView = false


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecipeViewHolder
    {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding: ViewRecipesItemBinding =
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.view_recipes_item, parent, false)

        return RecipeViewHolder(binding, context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listToUse.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecipeViewHolder, position: Int)
    {

        val recipe = listToUse[position]
        // to delete and edit items
        val dao = RecipesDatabase.getInstance(context).recipeDao()

        val repository = RecipeRepository(dao)
        recipesViewModel = RecipesViewModel(repository)
        //display data on list item
        holder.bind(recipe)
        Glide.with(context).load(recipe.imageOne)
                .into(holder.binding.imageViewItemImage)
        //tried to handle clicks here through the viewModel but I could not get it working from fragment
        //the function call after viewModel calls is what works and it seems to work well
        holder.binding.imageButtonItemdelete.setOnClickListener {
            recipesViewModel.setIsDelete(true)
            recipesViewModel.setPositionFromAdapter(position)
            startDeleteDialog(position)
        }
        holder.binding.imageButtonItemedit.setOnClickListener {
            recipesViewModel.setIsView(false)
            recipesViewModel.setPositionFromAdapter(position)
            isView = false
            startEditOrViewDialog(position)
        }
        holder.binding.imageButtonItemview.setOnClickListener {
            recipesViewModel.setIsView(true)
            recipesViewModel.setPositionFromAdapter(position)
            isView = true
            startEditOrViewDialog(position)
        }

    }

    fun setList(newList: List<Recipe>)
    {
        listToUse = newList
    }

    //dialog functions for the edit, delete, and view buttons on each item
    private fun startDeleteDialog(position: Int)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete recipe?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                    recipesViewModel.deleteRecipe(recipes[position])
                    notifyItemRemoved(position)
                }
                .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }.show()
    }

    private fun startEditOrViewDialog(position: Int)
    {
        when (isView)
        {
            true ->
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("View recipe?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                            //get relevant data from current recipe
                            val recipe = recipes[position]
                            //create a dialog that shows this data in an inflated layout
                            val viewDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_or_view, null)

                            view.editText_editrecipe_directions.setText(recipe.directions)
                            view.editText_editrecipe_ingredients.setText(recipe.ingredients)
                            view.editText_editrecipe_notes.setText(recipe.notes)
                            view.editText_editrecipe_title.setText(recipe.title)
                            view.textView_date_edit.text = recipe.date
                            view.editText_editrecipe_title.keyListener = null
                            view.editText_editrecipe_directions.keyListener = null
                            view.editText_editrecipe_ingredients.keyListener = null
                            view.editText_editrecipe_notes.keyListener = null
                            if (recipe.rating != null)
                            {
                                view.ratingBar_edit.rating = recipe.rating
                            }
                            Glide.with(context)
                                    .load(recipe.imageOne)
                                    .into(view.imageView_addphoto_edit)
                            viewDialog.setView(view).show()
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }.show()
            }
            false ->
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Edit recipe?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                            //get relevant data from current recipe
                            val recipe = recipes[position]
                            val idString = recipe.id.toString()
                            recipesViewModel.setId(idString)
                            recipesViewModel.getRecipeById2(idString)
                            notifyDataSetChanged()

                            val controller = parentFragment.findNavController()
                            controller.navigate(
                                ViewRecipesFragmentDirections.actionNavViewrecipesToNavAddrecipe(
                                    recipe.id.toString()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }.show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long
    {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int
    {
        return position
    }


    class RecipeViewHolder(val binding: ViewRecipesItemBinding, val context: Context) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    {

        fun bind(recipe: Recipe)
        {
            if (recipe.isLeftover == true)
            {
                binding.tvIsLeftovers.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            binding.textViewItemTitle.text = recipe.title

            if (recipe.date != null)
            {
                binding.textViewItemDate.text = recipe.date
            }
            if (recipe.rating != null)
            {
                binding.ratingBar2.rating = recipe.rating
            }
            binding.root.animation = AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f).apply {
                duration = 1000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view model, with live data variables set up that I could not get working in the fragment that this RecyclerView is in:

```
class RecipesViewModel(private val repository: RecipeRepository) : ViewModel()
{
    val recipesList = repository.getAllRecipes()

    private val _isView = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isView: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = _isView

    private val _isEdit = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isEdit: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = _isEdit

    private val _positionFromAdapter = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val positionFromAdapter: MutableLiveData<Int> = _positionFromAdapter

    private val _isDelete = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isDelete: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = _isDelete

    private val _recipesListFromSearch = MutableLiveData<List<Recipe>>()
    val recipesListFromSearch: LiveData<List<Recipe>> = _recipesListFromSearch

    private val _recipe = MutableLiveData<Recipe>()

    val recipe: LiveData<Recipe> = _recipe

    lateinit var searchString: String

    val savedId = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setPositionFromAdapter(position: Int)
    {
        _positionFromAdapter.value = position
    }

    fun setIsView(isView: Boolean)
    {
        _isView.value = isView
    }

    fun setIsDelete(isDelete: Boolean)
    {
        _isView.value = isDelete
    }

    fun setIsEdit(isEdit: Boolean)
    {
        _isEdit.value = isEdit
    }

    fun setId(id: String)
    {
        savedId.value = id
    }

    fun insertRecipe(recipe: Recipe)
    {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            repository.insertRecipe(recipe)
        }
    }

    fun getRecipesFromQuery(query: String)
    {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val list = repository.getRecipesSearch(query)
            MainScope().launch { _recipesListFromSearch.value = list }
        }
    }

    fun saveUserRecipeToDb(
        title: String?,
        ingredients: String?,
        directions: String?,
        notes: String?,
        uriToSave: String?,
        rating: Float?,
        date: String?,
        isLeftover: Boolean,
        loadedId: String
    ): Boolean
    {
        val recipeToSave = Recipe(
            title,
            ingredients,
            directions,
            notes,
            uriToSave,
            null,
            null,
            rating,
            date,
            isLeftover
        )
        if (loadedId != "666")
        {
            recipeToSave.id = loadedId.toInt()
        }
        insertRecipe(recipeToSave)
        return false
    }

    fun getRecipeById2(id: String) = repository.getRecipeByIdLive(id)

    fun deleteRecipe(recipe: Recipe)
    {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            repository.deleteRecipe(recipe)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to implement `onClick` in the RecyclerView. Let's assume that in Your Recycler every view is a visualization of some `item` and when You click on it You want to do something with that item:

1. Create class: `ClickListener`:

```
class ClickListener(
    val clickListener: (itemId: Int) -> Unit,
)
{
    fun onClick(item: ItemClass) = clickListener(item.id)
}
```

2. Now in Your RecylerViewAdapter pass as an argument this Listener:

```
class RecylerViewAdapter(
    private val clickListener: ClickListener
)
```

3. In `onBindViewHolder` pass this Listenner as argument

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
{
    holder.bind(getItem(position)!!, clickListener)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
{
    return ViewHolder.from(
        parent
    )
}
```

4. In Your ViewHolder class:

```
class ViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: ItemRecyclerBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
{
    companion object
    {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder
        {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemRecyclerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(
                binding
            )
        }
    }


    fun bind(
        item : Item,
        clickListener: ClickListener
    )
    {
        binding.item = item
        binding.clickListener = clickListener
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
}
```

5. In Your item layout (which has to be converted to data binding layout) add this:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.example.sth.database.Item" /> // path to `Item`
    <variable
        name="clickListener"
        type="com.example.sth.ui.adapter.ClickListener" /> // Path to `ClickListener`
</data>
```

6. Now You can add `onClick` method to Button:

```
android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(item)}"
```

7. When You create Adapter in fragment or Activity You have to pass `clickListenner` as a parameter. In this way You can handle everything from fragment and RecyclerView doesn't care about what You do in this function.

```
val clickListenner = ClickListenner(
    { id -> viewModel.clickItemWithid(id) }, // click. This function from ViewModel will be executed when You click on item in recycler View
)

val adapter = RecylerViewAdapter (
    clickListenner
)
```

---

*This method is based on Google developers codelabs on Udacity.

[Here You can check whole codelabs. It is free](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/ee5a525f-0ba3-4d25-ba29-1fa1d6c567b8/concepts/a24d8fdb-64ab-419c-bb29-c1225e104fa9).

[And here is just one video with implementing click listenner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=g8GDLOMt600&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=Udacity)*

Comment: I have been trying to make this work for 3 separate image buttons within each item, and I am not sure exactly how to differentiate them using this example.  This just takes a single click for the whole view, while I am looking for button clicks from inside of each view.  I do need to use the recipe id for the database removal/editing, but also need to show separate dialogs depending on which of the buttons was clicked.  How would you modify this to accommodate that need?

Comment: Your Click listener must have 3 functions click1, click2, click3. And now You have to pass them in the constructor. Then in `bind` function, You don't set clickListenner for the whole view but just for one ImageView. If You couldn't do it tell me and I will write the full project for You

Answer (score 0):

These are the changes that are working for me now:

```
    class ClickListener(val clickListener: (itemId: Int, itemPosition: Int, dialogInt: Int) -> Unit) {
fun onClickDelete(recipe: Recipe, position: Int, dialogInt: Int) = clickListener(recipe.id, position, dialogInt)
fun onClickEdit(recipe: Recipe, position: Int, dialogInt: Int) = clickListener(recipe.id, position, dialogInt)
fun onClickView(recipe: Recipe, position: Int, dialogInt: Int) = clickListener(recipe.id, position, dialogInt)
}
```

In the adapter:

```
class RecipeViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ViewRecipesItemBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): RecipeViewHolder{
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ViewRecipesItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return RecipeViewHolder(binding)
        }

    }
        fun bind(recipe: Recipe, clickListener: ClickListener) {
            binding.recipe = recipe
            binding.imageButtonItemdelete.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.onClickDelete(recipe, adapterPosition, 1)
            }
            binding.imageButtonItemedit.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.onClickEdit(recipe, adapterPosition,2)
            }
            binding.imageButtonItemview.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.onClickView(recipe, adapterPosition,3)
            }
            binding.executePendingBindings()

        binding.root.animation = AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f).apply {
            duration = 1000
        }
    }
```

In the fragment holding the RecyclerView :

```
   private fun initRecyclerView() {
    recipesViewModel.recipesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      //update recyclerview
        val list = it
        listForFragment = it
        clickListener = ClickListener { id, position, dialogInt ->
            recipesViewModel.apply {
                setPositionFromAdapter(position)
                setDialogRecipe(id)
            }
            when (dialogInt) {
                1 -> startDeleteDialog(position)
                2 -> startEditDialog(position)
                3 -> startViewDialog(position)
            }
        }
        rv_viewrecipes.adapter = ViewRecipesAdapter(requireContext(), list, this, clickListener)

        rv_viewrecipes.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    })
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to pass the position and int for the when statement through the xml onClick, but for now at least the adapter class has the view logic removed.